# Get Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop error on sending post request to login

Tags: node.js, json, express, session, postman

I have seen multiple answers on SO and tried to fix my code but it did not work. I have a post route for login and a middleware function only to update a comment and not for login:

routes = blogs.js:

```
    function checkString(string){
  if(string === undefined) throw 'Empty input';
  if(string === null) throw 'Null input';
  if(typeof(string) !== 'string') throw 'Input provided is not a string';
  if(string.trim().length === 0) throw 'Empty string on input';
}


router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {

  let { username,password } = req.body;
try{
  checkString(username);
  checkString(password);
  username = username.toLowerCase();
  if (!username.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$/g)) throw 'Only alphanumeric characters allowed for username'
  if(!password.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$/g)) throw 'Only alphanumeric and special characters allowed for password'
  if (username.length<4) throw 'Username should have 4 characters or more';
  if (password.length<6) throw 'Password should have 6 characters or more';
  
  
const ans = await userData.checkUser(username,password)

if (ans==1){
  
  const [id,user,name,pass] = await userData.getValues(username);
  req.session.user = { username:user, name:name, password:pass, userId:id };
  res.send({authenticated:true}) 
  }
} catch(e){
res.send(400,{msg:e})
}

});
```

Middleware function:

```
  app.use('/blog/:id', (req,res,next) => {
  if ( req.path == '/blog/login') next();
  if (!req.session.user) {
    res.status(404)
    res.send('Please login')
  }
  else {
    if (!data.sameUser(req.session.user.userId)){
      res.status(403);
      res.send('You can only change your comment')
    }
    else{
    next();
    }
}
});
```

checkUser:

```
async checkUser(username,password){
            checkString(username);
            checkString(password);
            username = username.toLowerCase()
            if (!username.match(/^[0-9a-z]+$/)) throw 'Only alphanumeric characters allowed'
            if(!password.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$/g)) throw 'Only alphanumeric and special characters allowed'
            if (username.length<4) throw 'Username should have 4 characters or more'
            if (password.length<6) throw 'Password should have 6 characters or more'
            const usersCollection = await users();
            const finder = await usersCollection.findOne({username:username});
            if (!finder) throw 'Cannot find your account, please try again or sign up'
            const compare = await bcrypt.compare(password,finder.password);
            console.log('data')
            if(compare) {
                console.log('beta')
                //return {authenticated: true};
                return 1;
            }
            else throw 'Either the username of password is invalid'

        }
```

I tried to send a post request from postman to this route but I get the following error:

```
Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop http://localhost:3000/blog/login
```

Postman returns correct output if I comment out the middleware function, I want to use the middlware only to check if the user is logged in for other routes and not the login. How can I correct the middleware function?

Comment: Can you post the code of the `checkUser` function?

Comment: I added the checkUser function, but pretty sure the middleware function is the problem because it works when I remove it